# Issue with inserting data from an iterator into a list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, compiler-errors, iterator

I have 2 sets of very similar code. I want to stress they are not in sequence or even in the same program. I just have them side by side for illustrative purposes:

```
std::list<int*> bob;
int * j = new int;
*j = 5;
bob.push_front(j);
std::list<int>::const_iterator goop = bob.begin();
bob.push_front(*goop); //takes issue with inserting goop
```

---

```
std::list<int> bob;
j = 5;
bob.push_front(j);
std::list<int>::const_iterator goop = bob.begin();
bob.push_front(*goop); //inserts goop just fine
```

The first is a list of pointers to integers, the second just integers.
The first takes issue with me dereferencing the iterator when trying to insert, complaining about typage, specifically wanting "**int * const &**"

What's going on here? What am I misconstruing about how iterators reference their underlying data and how must I execute the second case so I can insert into a list from an iterator of a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
std::list<int>::const_iterator goop = bob.begin();
```

to this:

```
std::list<int*>::const_iterator goop = bob.begin();
```

since you want **pointers to integers**, in your *first* example.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator you are using is a `list<int>::const_iterator` but you are using it to iterate over a `list<int*>`.

You will need to use a `list<int*>::const_iterator` to iterate over a `list<int*>`.

Comment: Paul, it seems I was doubly faster than you! :) But we agree on what the solution is, don't we? :) +1!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your confusion. The `list` part is completely irrelevant. What you are trying to do here is:

```
int* j = new int;
int i = j;  // illegal, pointer vs integer
j = i;  // illegal, integer vs pointer
```

It's as simple as that.

```
std::list<int*> bob;
```

bob is a list of *pointers* to `int`eger values (`int*`). It's value type is quite simply `int*`.

```
int * j = new int;
```

`j` is a pointer to an integer

```
*j = 5;
```

this line is utterly irrelevant to the issue.

```
bob.push_front(j);
```

this pushes the address of the recent allocation onto the front of the list. Not the value 5, the address of the memory.

```
std::list<int>::const_iterator goop = bob.begin();
```

`goop` is an iterator of a list with a value type `int`, not `int*`, so this line does not compile (http://ideone.com/zfmvPR) because `list<int>` and `list<int*>` are completely separate types.

```
bob.push_front(*goop); //takes issue with inserting goop
```

If the previous line *had* compiled, this would be illegal because `*goop` has the type `int` but `bob`'s value type is `int*` not `int`.

`bob.push_front` takes an `int*`. `*goop` would be an `int`.

Perhaps you should consider leveraging the `auto` keyword from C++11

```
std::list<int*> bob;
bob.push_front(new int);
auto it = bob.begin();  // std::list<int*>::iterator it = bob.begin();
// or auto it = bob.cbegin();   if you want a const_iterator
pop.push_front(*it);
```

But if you're going to use C++11 and your list is responsible for ownership of these pointers, you should probably consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead, since the code you've shown doesn't show use of `delete`.

```
std::list<unique_ptr<int>> bob;
```

It's also *much* clearer now when you make this mistake:

```
std::list<unique_ptr<int>> bob;
std::list<int> sally;  // clearly not compatible with bob.
```